# Sending multiple transactions from different wallets to a single adress (Without smart contract)

Tags: transactions

Imagine the following scenario:

I have 10 wallets with 1 ETH each.
I want to send a 1 ETH transaction from each of these wallets to 
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

The solution "Use a smart contract" is not the solution I'm looking for.

Besides doing this manually, what tool would you use to achieve this as fast as possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can jus automatize the execution of the transactions using any tool the allows you to interact with the network.

For instance, this is very easy to do with python and web3py, The only thing you need is a list containing the addresses and a for loop through it to send the transactions.

Step One: Code (I feeled the values with random numbers for the example)

1. Get the infura link for mainnet and paste in the line 2 instad of 'https://--infuralink'
2. In accounTarget write the address to which you want to send the ether
3. In accountList write the addresses from which you will send ether
4. In privatekeys write the private keys of the addresses in accountList, in order.
5. save the code in a file with .py extension.

"""

```
from web3 import Web3, HTTPProvider
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider('https://--infuralink'))


accountTarget = '0xfba3F929D2116868A77986cE017c91cCee3B03d9'
accountList = ['a905556532f8353195f389824fa34ea8f9719517', '0x7fd094cddd9d824b690c894ddbae63378d9de30b']
privatekeys = ['0x4c0562a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318', 
               '0x7c283a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318']


for i in range(0,len(accountList)):
    transaction = {
     'to': accountTarget,
     'value': w3.toWei(1,'ether'),
     'gas': 200000,
     'gasPrice': w3.eth.gasPrice,
     'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(w3.toChecksumAddress(accountList[i])),
     'chainId': 1
     }

    signed = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, privatekeys[i])
    w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```

Step two: Requirements.

1. You need to have python installed, see here [how to install python 3.6](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/common/handouts/pythoneclipsejava/python.html)
2. Install web3 by doing in the command line (cmd) `pip3 install web3`

Step 3 run the code

1. in the command line write `python3 filename.py`
2. The code will print the transactionhash, so you can check them

You may try this in a test network first (I test it on rinkeby)

Hope this help.

Comment: Would you be willing to go more in depth on this? I would pay ETH for a tool and a walkthrough.

Comment: Sure, I will elaborate it. Are you running a node in your computer?

Comment: No, I am using Quiknode.

Comment: I just posted the piece of code needed, I am assuming you have some knowledge of python. I do not know anything about your node so you will need to add the path to it. I hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: I do not have knowledge of python. I am basically a noob in all this. Things I don't know: Where do I run the code you just posted, where to I put my wallet adresses (private keys is probably "passwords", so I understand that one I think), where do I put gas price? It would be fantastic if you could explain me where to run this code and fill the "gaps" with random data, so I can exactly see where I have to put my own data. Like this for instance: Put 5 adresses on the account list with random private keys, put the gas price to 100 gwei etc. etc.

Comment: I will pay you 0.1 ETH (will check if I have more on my other accounts) if you help me get this running/working :)

Comment: I feel like I can just use this tool: https://github.com/wealdtech/ethereal --- seems a lot more simple, what do you think?

Comment: Looks cool, but it works if your accounts are local, meaning that you have a node running on your computer. I still do not understand if you have the keyfiles or the pair of public and private key, the code I posted works if you have the keyfile and the `passworsd1`, etc, refer to the password of the keyfile.

Comment: I am now using an infura node (ropsten - for testing purposes). I have no clue how/where I put my keyfiles so the code can grab them. Like I said, I am really new to this. Also: Do I just copy/paste the code into a new *.py file and launch it?

Comment: having the node will make the things easy but I will have to change the code. if you have your private keys or if you can have it makes it easy. I will update the code and will tell you how to input the needed information. You need to have python 3.5 or above and to install web3 using `pip install web3`. I am also thinking JavaScript may be more straight forward. I will be back to you in the afternoon

Comment: I can use keystore files or the private keys, it doesn't really matter. If private keys are easier, that's totally fine! Like I said, I am an amateur, so it helps me a ton if you tell me "Paste this into the console, then this, then this etc." I would be eternally thankful :)

Comment: I updated the answer and wrote the step. I hope this help you. Let me know

Comment: I put the code into an answer :)

Comment: Here is the complete lines:

accountList = ['0x17e6FAe5E6962000b36c9aDEA516AF6805EE76D5', '0x830b6d581F6bf309F81Bcd49c6F0E1626cE0B87C']
privatekeys = ['3553545437777533029944009300a2aaaa209390030ee0239334323403202430', '3553545437777533029532342300a2aaaa209390030ee0239334323403202430']    ----- The keys are correct. Maybe the format is incorrect?

Comment: wait, I just saw the error, the parameter `chainId: 1` is valid for the main net, but you are using ropsten, for ropsten the value is 3

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much! Send me an Ethereum adress per dm please and I will send you the ETH as soon as I get it from the exchange! <3

Comment: You can see my address in my profile. Good luck and do not forget to accept the answer.